# It is valid to ask how and how much to charge for some things?

Tags: discussion

What happens is that I would like to know what would be a fair price for a simple action that a client wants me to perform.

For example if I asked something like "How much would it cost to make a facebook page?" In the main forum, such questions would be valid.

I am curious as to whether such questions are valid in the forum.

Answer (score 6):

Based on how I've been closing question:

If a user is asking a very open ended question with no detail, it gets closed as either Primarily Opinion Based or Too Broad. This would include short questions like "My client wants me to build x y and z, how much should I charge?"

This type of question is bad for a magnitude of reasons:

- Where do you live?
- What experience do you have?
- How long do you think it would take?
- Have you done it before?
- Will the client actually pay?
- How much break-in time will you need?
- How much time will the client take to pay?
- What is the standard of living for your area?
- What are you Freelancing costs?
- What happens if this client ghosts?

There are too many variables to give a good answer. Therefore, one of the questions I link to constantly when someone asks what to charge includes *how* to determine what to charge. As the old adage goes, "Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, he's fed for life". We need to teach these Freelancers to be self-sufficient to a point.

I may be wrong, but I'd welcome the discussion. But don't expect me to leave questions upvoted and open if they don't have at *least* half the questions above answered.

Answer (score 2):

No one, I mean, **no one**, can price anything for anyone else.

Individual pricing entails so many varying factors that are all relative to the individual/business.

- My overhead **won't** be the same as *your* overhead.
- My target clients may not be *your* target clients
- My experience **won't** be the same as your experience
- My skills **won't** be the same as *your* skills
- I **won't** fully grasp any project you may mention because I'm not privy to **all** communication

Anyone throwing out numbers is **guessing** based upon their own inclination. They can't possibly be using correct formulations to arrive at an adequate price based upon a specific project.

There is simply no way for anyone to accurately price **services** for another individual. You may as well pick a number out of your hat that seems correct to you.... because that's all any answer will be doing.